Prove or Disprove that if $S$ and $A$ are independent, and $S$ and $B$ are independent, then $S$ is independent of $(A \land B)$
Intuitively it seems that this statement is true.
Simple examples that I took also showed that when $S$ and $A$ are independent, and $S$ and $B$ are independent, then $S$ is independent of $A \land B$ irrespective of whether $A$ and $B$ are independent. But a few positive examples are not a conclusive proof.

Given

$P(S | A) = P(S)$
$P(S | B) = P(S)$

To Prove/Disprove
$P(S | (A\land B)) = P(S)$
$$\begin{align*}
P(S | A) &= P(S) \\ 
\implies P(S \land A) &= P(S) \cdot P(A) \\[1em]
P(S | B) &= P(S) \\ 
\implies P(S \land B) &= P(S) \cdot P(B) \\[1em]
\hline
P(S | (A\land B)) &= \frac{P(S \land (A\land B))}{P(A\land B)}\\[1em]
&= \frac{P(S \land A \land B)}{P(A\land B)}\\[1em]
\end{align*}$$
what do I do after this?

What does that wedge thingy mean? Are you taking a min/max or intersection? Are $A, B$ random variables or events?  Assuming $A,B,S$ are events and we use $\cap$, then the statement is false. You can independently flip two coins and let $A={\mbox{First flip is heads}}$ and $B={\mbox{Second flip is heads}}$.

A, B, and S are events. $\land$ is the logical and symbol (analogous to intersection in this case). Apologies for the mixed notation.

Orthogonal: (a) while '∧' is analogous to '∩', 'A∩B' but not 'A∧B' is an event; (b) The argument $-2=2 ⟹ (-2)^2=2^2 ⟹ 4=4$ is valid and its conclusion $4=4$ is true, but its premise $-2=2$ is false.

Flip a fair coin twice and let the events be:

$A$: the first flip is heads.
$B$: the second flip is heads.
$S$: the two flips are the same.

Then $P(S|A) = P(S|\neg A) = P(S|B) = P(S|\neg B) = 1/2$ but $P(S|A \wedge B) = 1$ and $P(S|\neg (A \wedge B)) = 1/3$.

Ah.. this was simpler than I imagined. Thanks for the quick counterexample :)
